# Django Project - bootstrap navigation with javascript script not working - Where should JavaScript go?

Tags: javascript, django, navigation

I have a Django project, in which I have a simple front-end bootstrap horizontal navigation bar (taken from here: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_tab_js&stacked=h).

In it, a user clicks on a tab, and it displays the information for that tab, on click.

In this case, I have used django templating language and crispy forms to generate a form inside tab 1. This renders fine, and looks correct in terms of formatting and layout, but, the tabs are not functional. I have looked at other stackoverflow questions, but none are specific to what I am asking.

The functionality of the tabs, I assume, is controlled by the Javascript code snippet:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".nav-tabs a").click(function(){
    $(this).tab('show');
  });
});
</script>
```

As a newbie to Django and front-end design, I am struggling to see, a) where I have made the mistake and what needs to be corrected in order for the tabs to function correctly on-click. b) how javascript is implemented inside of the whole structure of a Django html template.

By this,I mean, Javascript is usually put inside the 'head' tags, but in this case templates extend a base template in which there is a head, so I am unsure of where Javascript should go.  Should I for example, be using external Javascript files in each case? What is best practice? Where should it go in relation to where the "{% blocks" (start and end) go?

A useful answer would

a) point out the error in the code such that my tabs will work
b) explain a little about the layout/structure of where JavaScript snippets go, which add to html/boostrap functionality, inside of a Django-based template and within the framework of using Django Templating language.

The whole code for my **profile.html** is shown below

```
{% extends "socialmedia/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

    <div class="content-section">
      <div class="media">
        <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}">
        <div class="media-body">
          <h2 class="account-heading">{{ user.username }}</h2>
          <p class="text-secondary">{{ user.email }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container mt-3">

  <br>
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#home">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#menu1">Tab 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#menu2">Tab 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#menu3">Tab 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
      <h3>Tab 1</h3>
      <p>Please fill in your account/profile information here.</p>


     <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Profile Information</legend>
            {{u_form|crispy}}
            {{p_form|crispy}}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Update....</button>
        </div>
    </form>
   </div>
    </div>

    <div id="menu1" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Tab 2</h3>
      <p>Tab 2 information here</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Tab 3</h3>
      <p>Tab 3 information will go here</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Calendar</h3>
      <p>Manage your Calendar</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}   
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".nav-tabs a").click(function(){
    $(this).tab('show');
  });
});
</script>
```

What I've tried: I have tried putting the javascript code in various places - such as before the {% endblock content %} and at the top of the page, but neither has worked.

Update:

I noticed that above the cdn/css hasn't been added. On adding this, it messes up the formatting, and the on-click, sort of works, but not correctly.

The updated code is as below. Again, I'd need suggestions as to where to correctly place this block of code for correct formatting and functionality, as well as the javascript code.

```
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Updated **profile.html**

The following now renders the page incorrectly, moving up the image at the top and the username and email variables in an undesirable fashion. Furthermore, the tabs work, but not completely. The crispy form is generated in each tab, instead of just the first, and the content of the other tabs is shown underneath.

```
{% extends "socialmedia/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

<!--- this code has been added as per the update above -->

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



    <div class="content-section">
      <div class="media">
        <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}">
        <div class="media-body">
          <h2 class="account-heading">{{ user.username }}</h2>
          <p class="text-secondary">{{ user.email }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container mt-3">

  <br>
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#home">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#menu1">Tab 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#menu2">Tab 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#menu3">Tab 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
      <h3>Tab 1</h3>
      <p>Please fill in your account/profile information here.</p>


     <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Profile Information</legend>
            {{u_form|crispy}}
            {{p_form|crispy}}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Update....</button>
        </div>
    </form>
   </div>
    </div>

    <div id="menu1" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Tab 2</h3>
      <p>Tab 2 information here</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Tab 3</h3>
      <p>Tab 3 information will go here</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Calendar</h3>
      <p>Manage your Calendar</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}   
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".nav-tabs a").click(function(){
    $(this).tab('show');
  });
});
</script>
```

I am also including my base template, **base.html** (which does include a head and a body) below.

```
{% load static %}
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

{% if title %}
    <title>Fakebook Blog Posts - {{title}}</title>
{% else %}
    <title>Fakebook Blog</title>
{% endif %}

<!--this is django templating language-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'worldguestbook\main2.css' %}"/>

</head>
<body>

<header class="site-header">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="/">FakeBook Newsfeed</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle" aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
        <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'socialmedia-home' %}">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'socialmedia-about' %}">About</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Navbar Right Side -->
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'post-create' %}">New Post</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'profile' %}">Profile</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>

            {% else %}
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<main role="main" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
                <div class="alert alert-{{message.tags}}">
                    {{ message }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}

      {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="content-section">
        <h3>Our Sidebar</h3>
        <p class='text-muted'>You can put any information here you'd like.
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Latest Posts</li>
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Announcements</li>
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Calendars</li>
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">etc</li>
          </ul>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I came across a possible answer (not on stackoverflow) which suggested, that adding a DTL block in the base template like this:

```
{% block extra_js %}{% endblock extra_js %}
```

and then adding the script inside those tags in the profile.html page, would work, but it hasn't either. (see below addition that I've tried)

added to the **base.html**...

```
<body>
{% block extra_js %}{% endblock extra_js %}

<header class="site-header">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
```

in the **profile.html** ....

```
      <h3>Calendar</h3>
      <p>Manage your Calendar</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% block extra_js %}
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".nav-tabs a").click(function(){
    $(this).tab('show');
  });
});
</script>
{% endblock extra_js %}
{% endblock content %}
```

The above, doesn't work at all.

But, on adding even more additional blocks to the base, and then adding the css in those blocks in the profile.html, the same problem as described above occurs. (tabs are clickable, but the form content is shown in all of them, and also the tab content is generated at the bottom like an overflow).

To clarify, the below is added to profile.html

```
{% block extra_css %}
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
{% endblock extra_css %}
```

with this added to **base.html** (in the head)

```
<head>
{% block extra_css %}{% endblock extra_css %}
```

Comment: Please see update above!

Comment: The answer that would adequately help me, and anyone after me, would include information and clarity on where to put the script files (bootstrap and javascript script  snippet).

Comment: Did you have it fixed? Having similar issue here.